# Securely Authenticate iPhone App to Server?

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

What is the best/easiest way to authenticate a user from an iPhone client to  a PHP/MySQL web-service? I have not set any authentication up and I want to keep track of the user so when I call my services it sends the username. I want to make sure this user is unique and if they lose their phone they will be able to re-download app and login with credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very open ended question. Can you please provide some use cases that way we can help. If you are talking about Secure Authentication then just use HTTPS:

HTTPS was designed specifically to:

1)use encryption to defend against packet-sniffing

2)use certificates signed by an authority to defend against MITM

Comment: Do you mean SSL certificates? If so, I think they're too expensive to start... Any alternatives or cheaper certificates?

Comment: You can use Amazon EC2 and S3 to do all the thing using PHP/MySQL. It does required some learning curve but once you now its very simple to work on secure authentication services.

Comment: I've looked a little into Amazon EC2 and S3 but don't know where to start. Do you know of any awesome resources to start with?